# Nexus Repository OSS 3 upload WHL file to pypi-internal results in Error 404

Tags: nexus3

I work with Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.7.1.

I try to break the coming packages on groups.

I have created group via the admin panel. I have added a repository to the host group.

I have stated in the *.pypirc file to url the address on groups:

```
[distutils] 
index-servers =     

nexus

nexus-master

[nexus] 
repository: http://nexus.domen.com:8081/repository/pypi/

username:admin 

password:admin123    

[nexus-master] 

repository: http://nexus.domen.com:8081/repository/pypi-master/ 

username:admin

password:admin123
```

Now I am confused to send a package to the server:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r nexus-master
```

the server tears off connection.

> Submitting dist\package-0.1.3.whl to
>   http://nexus.domen.com:8081/repository/pypi-master/ Upload failed
>   (404): Not Found error: Upload failed (404): Not Found

How it fixed? Thanks